# Sweetness of raw stevia leaves?

Tags: houseplants, herbs

This may sound like a no-brainer to those who have stevia plants, but here goes. My question is, can I rub the leaves of a mature stevia plant with my fingers and then taste intense sweetness on my fingers thereafter? If so, what age/height/fulness constitutes a "mature" stevia plant? I have used Bolivian imported stevia in my coffee for quite a while now, and I am considering doing a venture and investment of my own in some stevia plants to process the leaves myself. But I was just curious if the raw, green leaf emits sweetness.

Comment: From experience, the raw leaves are sweet. Not as intense as the extract.

Comment: I noticed something online the other day that chewing raw stevia leaves can curb a sugar craving, as the faint sweet taste remains in the mouth for at least an hour. Perhaps that answers my question, but I would appreciate anyone verifying this by personal experience.

Comment: The aftertaste does linger perhaps an hour or so.

Comment: I used powdered stevia, and it tasted like a stronger sugar substitute